# Web Api 2 - Populating Default Values on Complex Query String Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a REST API using ASP.Net Web API 2.  I have a GET endpoint that accepts a complex object from the query string.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync([FromUri]SpendingAccountSearchParams spendingAccountSearchParams) {...}
```

The search object has a lot of properties that are either nullable or have default values populated in the constructor of the object. For example:

```
public SpendingAccountSearchParams()
{
    AsOfDate = DateTime.Now;
    Skip = 0;
    Top = 20;
}
```

If I pass at least 1 of the parameters in the query string then my SpendingAccountSearchParams object get populated in the controller and all of the default values are set correctly.

However, if I don't pass ANY of the values then my SpendingAccountSearchParams object is null in the constructor.

How can I AUTOMATICALLY force all the properties to get their default values if no query string parameters are passed?

I want the equivalent of this, but obviously it isn't valid and doesn't work:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync([FromUri]SpendingAccountSearchParams? spendingAccountSearchParams = new SpendingAccountSearchParams()) {...}
```

I know that within the Controller I could check for null and create a new object if it doesn't exist, but this is just one example of one endpoint.  Ultimately I will have lots of endpoints all with different search parameters and I want it to happen automatically for all of them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use Model binder.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what Model binder is, can you point me to some more information about it?

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, it works out of the box if you use getters/setters instead of properties.

```
public SpendingAccountSearchParams()
{
    DateTime AsOfDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    int Skip { get; set; } = 0;
    int Top { get; set; } = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync([FromUri]SpendingAccountSearchParams spendingAccountSearchParams){
     if(spendingAccountSearchParams==null)
      {
         spendingAccountSearchParams.AsOfDate=DateTime.Now;
    spendingAccountSearchParams.Skip=0;
    spendingAccountSearchParams.Top=20;
     }
    else
    {
     // your code

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my original post "I know that within the Controller I could check for null and create a new object if it doesn't exist, but this is just one example of one endpoint. Ultimately I will have lots of endpoints all with different search parameters and I want it to happen automatically for all of them."

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want it to happen automatically for all of them then you should create a custom model binder.

Read up on [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> With a model binder, you have access to things like the HTTP request,
>   the action description, and the raw values from the route data.
>
> To create a model binder, implement the **IModelBinder** interface. This
>   interface defines a single method, **BindModel**:

```
bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext);
```

Here is a simplified model binder for `SpendingAccountSearchParams` objects.

```
public class SpendingAccountSearchParamsModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(SpendingAccountSearchParams)) {
            return false;
        }

        ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (val == null) {
            //create your default object
            var result = new SpendingAccountSearchParams();
            bindingContext.Model = result;
            return true;
        }

        //you could do other checks and add ModelState errors if needed 

        return true;
    }
}
```

You need to then register your binder.

You can add a **[ModelBinder]** attribute to the type. Web API will use the specified model binder for all parameters of that type.

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(SpendingAccountSearchParamsModelBinder))]
public class SpendingAccountSearchParams
{
    // ....
}
```